# how to keep publishing a same message in roslibjs

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, roslibjs

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone, I am trying to control a mobile robot using voice recognition through a website. The problem is my robot only move if a callback funtion of subcribe is call, which means subcriber keep receiving twist message. If I use a keyboard it would be easy because I just keep pushing the button. But I am using voice recognition so it takes a website a little time to recognise my voice and I can't keep talking to make my robot move. I tried to look at roslibjs API and I just find a throttle rate, which is "the rate (in ms in between messages) at which to throttle the topics". But it didn't work. I feel it like a latch option in rostopic pub command in terminal, it just publish 1 time and done, not any more. Thanks for reading and sorry for my english

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/351776/how-to-keep-publishing-a-same-message-in-roslibjs/) by [drtritm](https://answers.ros.org/users/50806/drtritm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 187 on 2020-05-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Well I find out that using function like setTimeout and setInterval in js will solve this problem

---

Originally posted by [drtritm](https://answers.ros.org/users/50806/drtritm/) with karma: 187 on 2020-05-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0